# ODI 11g Odi OSCommand Failed

Tags: oracle11g, command

I want to copy files from 192.168.155.10 (local) server to 212.115.10.50 server which is sftp server. I have a mistake doing this in ODI 11g. Help me.

I try it :

cp /source_files/reports/report1.txt RPR_Host:"pass123"@192.168.155.10:22/REPORTS/report1.txt -- Not Working

cp /source_files/reports/report1.txt sftp RPR_Host:"pass123"@192.168.155.10:22/REPORTS/report1.txt -- Not Working

cp /source_files/reports/report1.txt RPR_Host:"pass123"@sftp.192.168.155.10:22/REPORTS/report1.txt -- Not Working -- Not Working

Thanks.

works
failure
ODI 11g error

Comment: What does the word "Faile" means in the title, sorry?